# BIT shifting with AND operation in SQL select

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, bit-manipulation

I have a bit shifting to be done on NUMBER column in table.

It is something like (NUMBER & MASK) >> 27 .. and i need to compare the result of this. Is this something that can be done through SQL select query. So far i am using scripts to do this/

Comment: Assuming SQL Server, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx

Comment: What DBMS? Oracle? SQLServer? MySQL? Not all things with "SQL" in the name are the same.

Comment: @MPelletier It is Oracle

Answer (score 1):

Oracle's PL/SQL has a [BITAND()](http://www.jlcomp.demon.co.uk/faq/bitwise.html) function. Shift-right is the same as integer division by a power of 2. Assuming `X` is an integer, `X >> 27` is the same as `X / 134217728`.

Comment: And what about shift left?